# Error: The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002)

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, dll, filenotfoundexception

I have below object from the class which is referenced thrue dll and when it come to the below line it gives below error. The dll is referenced from GAC_MSIL directory on my local c drive. I trid movig dll to other place but getting same result. I copied the dll from dev machine to local.

`UserAccessor userAccessor = new UserAccessor();`

**Error: System.IO.FileNotFoundException was unhandled by user code
  Message=The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002)**

Comment: Did you set copy local = true?

Comment: Yes. But I get the same error.

Comment: Use Fuslogvw.exe to troubleshoot assembly resolution problems.

Comment: Do I need to do anything to place this dll in MSIL or I can copy past there?